# Using universal_io with injectable but HttpClient in the generated file is always from dart:io

Tags: flutter, injectable

I am trying to use `universal_io` for my flutter project in Web. At the same time, I am using `injectable`. However, in the generated file of injectable, `HttpClient` is always recognised from `dart:io` and eventually throw some mismatch errors. At the moment, I have to manually update the generated file to get my app working. Not sure if there is any better way to resolve it. Thank you.

Here is my code

I created a `regitser_module.dart`

```
import 'package:injectable/injectable.dart';
import 'package:universal_io/io.dart';

@module
abstract class RegisterModule {
//add http client
  @lazySingleton
  HttpClient get httpClient => newUniversalHttpClient();
}

class $RegisterModule extends RegisterModule {}
```

and then run `flutter packages pub run build_runner watch` to generate the file for injectable.

However, in the `injectable.config.dart` file, it has

```
import 'dart:io' as _i6;

...

gh.lazySingleton<_i6.HttpClient>(() => registerModule.httpClient);
```

When I start running the app, I get the following error.

```
lib/injectable.config.dart:88:55: Error: The argument type 'HttpClient/*1*/' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'HttpClient/*2*/'.
 - 'HttpClient/*1*/' is from 'dart:_http'.
 - 'HttpClient/*2*/' is from 'package:universal_io/src/http_client.dart' ('/D:/pub_cache/hosted/pub.dev/universal_io-2.2.2/lib/src/http_client.dart').
        () => _i15.GeneralServerService(httpClient: gh<_i6.HttpClient>()));
                                                      ^
lib/injectable.config.dart:90:21: Error: The argument type 'HttpClient/*1*/' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'HttpClient/*2*/'.
 - 'HttpClient/*1*/' is from 'dart:_http'.
 - 'HttpClient/*2*/' is from 'package:universal_io/src/http_client.dart' ('/D:/pub_cache/hosted/pub.dev/universal_io-2.2.2/lib/src/http_client.dart').
      httpClient: gh<_i6.HttpClient>(),
                    ^
Failed to compile application.
```